Image stretched when connecting MacBook to ultra-wide monitor
I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014), and I want to connect it to an ultra-wide monitor (3440 x 1440). I'm using an HDMI cable and wonder if DP cable would work better.
The monitor's resolution doesn't show up in the options in system settings -> displays, and the ones that are offered always result in a horizontally stretched image.
So I installed SwitchResX, and created a custom resolution of 3440 x 1440, and applied it. This results in the top and bottom areas of the monitor being black, and the image in the center still stretched, and this seems to happen for all 21:9 resolutions.
Side note: I've connected a PC to the monitor, both Windows and Ubuntu show the image correctly straight of the box, so I know the monitor works fine in principle using this HDMI cable and settings on the display itself.
Is there any way I can work around this issue from macOS side?

Welcome to Ask Different.  We strongly prefer one question per question, so I’ll edit this to be focused on what I see as the main consideration. Feel free to ask a follow on question if you need help selecting a new Mac based on this criteria.

I recall using the Dual Link DVI adapter with 30 inch cinema displays and pushing more pixels than you need so absolutely get a miniDP to DP cable to rule out HDMI being a problem is my advice. I always prefer DP over HDMI on displays that have both inputs for precisely this sort of behavior. Also, see if holding the option key results in other choices for detected resolution than the custom one you made.

thanks @bmike, I appreciate the effort. However, I'm open other solutions, not limited to macOS!

I’d ask that as a follow on question - if anyone has experience loading windows or Unix on that hardware to support displays?

I'm basically wondering if a newer macbook would be fit for this kind of display - but I don't know which specs to look for. I already have a pc, but i'd like to use a mac with it...

What does the manufacturer say?

Using a DisplayPort cable solved the issue.
